# A cave explorer is surveying a cave. She follows

Tags: vectors

A cave explorer is surveying a cave. She follows a passage $180$m straight west, then $210$m in a direction $45^\circ $ east of south and then $380$m at $30^\circ $ east of north. After a fourth unmeasured displacement she finds herself back where she started. Use the METHOD OF COMPONENTS to determine the magnitude and direction of the fourth displacement.

My Attempt:
Let, $\vec {A}=180 \textrm {m}$ 
$$\vec {B}=210 \textrm {m}$$
$$\vec {C}=280 \textrm {m}$$
$$\vec {D}=?$$
Calculating the $X$ components,
$$A_x=-180$$
$$B_x=148.49$$
$$C_x=140$$
$$D_x=?$$
Calculating the $Y$ components,
$$A_y=0$$
$$B_y=-148.49$$
$$C_y=242.49$$
$$D_y=?$$
How do I calculate further?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To get back to the original position, we need

$$A_x + B_x + C_x + D_x = 0$$

and

$$A_y + B_y + C_y + D_y = 0$$

Since only $D_x$ and $D_y$ are not known, we can solve for vector $D$.